# SQL join, compare two column values, match col values

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables.

```
Table 1 columns are
====================
(MAINID,  XID, Name)
====================
(A1   1  SAP)
(B2   2  BAPS)
(C3   3  SWAMI)

Table 2 columns are
===================
(ID  COL1)
=================== 
(1   XYZ)
(2   ABC)
```

Now, **I want to find which XID value is not in Table2's ID column**. In Table 1 XID is unique and also in Table 2 ID is PK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aln alternative solution is by using LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT tb1.*
FROM Table1 AS tb1 LEFT JOIN Table2 AS tb2
        ON tb1.XID = tb2.ID
WHERE tb2.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select xid 
from table1
where xid not in
(select id from table2)
```

Comment: This worked for me doing something similar and it also looks the simplest.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tipical case to use Sets difference, however, the solution provided by Rossana is faster than this one (not sure about Steve Howard solution):

```
select XID as ID from Table1
except
select ID from Table2;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/e7329/1)

This way you are obtaining those ID's from Table1 that are not in Table2.
Note this solution works in postgresql, other RDBMS uses a different clause as MINUS.

The next solution is faster than using IN and EXCEPT clauses:

```
select XID from Table1 t1
where (not exists (
  select ID from Table2 t2 where (t1.XID = t2.ID)
));
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c30a3/1)

Comment: What makes you think one of these solutions is faster than the others? Talks about efficiency make sense only in connection with a specific RDBMS. Some methods work faster in some products, others are preferable in others. You can't make conclusions without knowing what product the OP is using.